# values within two list

Tags: python, list, if-statement

So I have two list. For example:

```
list1 = [a1, b2, c3, f6]
list2 = [a1, b2, d4, e5]
```

And I want only values that uniquely appear within list2 to append to a new list. For example:

```
list3 = [d4, e5]
```

Comment: There is no `if loop` and your code is so far off that I think you should work through the [Python Tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/) first instead of playing whack-a-mole with names and comparison operators.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `list comprehension`.

```
list3 = [item for item in list2 if item not in list1]
```

Output

```
list3 = ['d4', 'e5']
```

Comment: Yes, but OP does not even know how to write a `for` loop, or how to use `list.append` or comparison operators properly. They will copy-paste your code and never learn them.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert `list1` to a set first so you can efficiently test if an item in list2 is in the set while you iterate over `list2`:

```
list1 = ['a1', 'b2', 'c3', 'f6']
list2 = ['a1', 'b2', 'd4', 'e5']
set1 = set(list1)
list3 = [i for i in list2 if i not in set1]
```

`list3` would become:

```
['d4', 'e5']
```